# How to sync multiple lightweight-chart canvas?

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm practicing lightweight-chart js library and now I can deal with horizontal sync mutliple charts. I build simple js code for that can move chart right and left at same time.

[image]

As far as I know, lightweight-chart doesn't support multi pane. I tried to sync multiple chart myself.

Problem is that, I cannot sync y-axis index width. Any insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, there's no out-of-box API to sync the main chart with multiple panes. However, the community came up with some ways how to implement exactly what you ask for. For more info check this https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/issues/50